# Search by tag using Deezer Api

Tags: deezer

Is there any way to do a search by tag in Deezer Api? For exemple to get the info equivalent to: 'http://www.deezer.com/tags/rock'. I've been trying for a while but I cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, you just do a normal search by artist or album looking for that tag and it returns the same results as in web